# How can I draw a circle around a specific object, not necessarily the object the script is attached to?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this script that draws a circle around the object the script is attached to.

I would like also to use the `centerObject` variable as an option to draw another circle around the `centerObject`, or just only around the `centerObject` and not the transform the script is attached to. I'm not sure how to do it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject centerObject;
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetLayers;
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, xRadius, targetLayers))
        {
            Debug.Log("player detected");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("player NOT detected");
        }
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

[image: Screenshot of script in action]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LineRenderer component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) has two modes of interpreting its positions: local space and world space.

In local space mode (default), all the positions are relative to the gameObject the line renderer is on. This is useful if you want the line to move when the object moves.

But in a scenario like yours, where you want the line to be relative to something other than the parent, it makes sense to enable "Use World Space" in the inspector settings. Now any points you set via `LineRenderer.SetPositions` are relative to the world origin.

When you enable that setting without changing your code, then the line should appear as it does now, but around the world origin instead of the gameObject.

If you want it to appear around an arbitrary `Vector3 center` instead, you would just add that vector to all the positions you calculate.

Another way to do this which does not just apply the position but also the rotation and scale of another gameObject would be to use the [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) method of that other transform. Whether that's desirable or not depends on your particular use-case.

Modified code for using only position:

```
    var centerPos = centerObject.transform.position;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
    {
        x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
        y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

        points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y) + centerPos;

        angle += (380f / segments);
    }
```

Modified code using position, rotation and scale:

```
    var centerTransform = centerObject.transform;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
    {
        x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
        y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

        points[i] = centerTransform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(x, height, y));

        angle += (380f / segments);
    }
```